# How to show the data that has already been saved in core data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, save, tableview

i want to show data that has already been saved in core data and i just want to preview it, just like have the data of books name saved in and show it on tableview. All the tutorials i have seen is till now is ,usually take text fields, enter the data, save it and then fetch it. please help me because this my first interaction with core data

Comment: You will have to do a bit more research than that. The tutorials you mention show you how to insert data, so you can do that without text fields.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you are trying to use the NSfetchedResults Controller. If your data is un an array to save it to core data its you do the following if you are using swift...

//create your array

```
var employee:NSMutableArray = []
employee.addObject(["name":"Bill","LastName":"Hanks"])
employee.addObject(["name":"Rolex","LastName":"Swarzer"])
employee.addObject(["name":"Clive","LastName":"Martin"])
employee.addObject(["name":"Jimi","LastName":"Hendrix"])
```

The add it to core data as follows:

```
let appDel = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDel.managedObjectContext

        for item in employee {
            do {
                let newUser = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Employee", inManagedObjectContext: context)
                newUser.setValue(item["name"], forKey: "name")
                newUser.setValue(item["LastName"], forKey: "lastname")
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                //do nothing
            }
        }
```

Assuming you know how to set up the UITableView and have called its property TableBox observe the following methods. You can copy and paste and just change what is necessary

//------------------------------------- load tableViewMethods -----

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return ""
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let sectionInfo = self.fetchedResultsController.sections![section]
    return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return (self.fetchedResultsController.sections?.count)!    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("theCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NSManagedObject
    self.configureCell(cell, withObject: object)

    return cell
}

func configureCell(cell: UITableViewCell, withObject object: NSManagedObject) {
    cell.textLabel!.text = object.valueForKey("name")!.description
    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = object.valueForKey("lastname")!.description
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableBox.moveRowAtIndexPath(sourceIndexPath, toIndexPath: destinationIndexPath)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .Delete {
        let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
        context.deleteObject(self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! NSManagedObject)

        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate.
            abort()
        }
    }
}
```

//-------- fetched results controller
 Just remember to change the Entity Name and the NSSortdescriptor key. Also change the tableBox property to whatever yours is named

```
var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController {
    if _fetchedResultsController != nil {
        return _fetchedResultsController!
    }
    let appDel = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDel.managedObjectContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Employee")

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    //fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
    _fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController

    do {
        try _fetchedResultsController!.performFetch()
    } catch {
        // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        //print("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController!
}
var _fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController? = nil

func controllerWillChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    self.tableBox.beginUpdates()
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeSection sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atIndex sectionIndex: Int, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
    switch type {
    case .Insert:
        self.tableBox.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    case .Delete:
        self.tableBox.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: sectionIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    default:
        return
    }
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
    switch type {
    case .Insert:
        tableBox.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    case .Delete:
        tableBox.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    case .Update:
        self.configureCell(tableBox.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)!, withObject: anObject as! NSManagedObject)
    case .Move:
        tableBox.moveRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!, toIndexPath: newIndexPath!)
    }
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(controller: NSFetchedResultsController) {
    self.tableBox.endUpdates()
}
```